# Sidebar On Click Infowindow Open, Data retrieved by XML

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have retrieved the data from xml..Generated Sidebar. I want to open infowindow on click on the sidebar.. Tried so many examples and codes but not succeeded... Can you please suggest what should be function declaration for myclick function:

Below i am mentioning my code...I will be grateful to you if any one can help!!

```
var gmarkers = [];

function load() {
 var side_bar_html = "<div class=\"pro_curved-hz-2\"><div class=\"pro_text-shadow\" style=\"height: 250px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y: scroll;\">";
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $SelectedLatitude; ?>,<?php echo $SelectedLongitude; ?>),
    zoom: <?php echo $Zoom; ?>,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("/map.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var count=markers.length;
    if(count>0)
    side_bar_html += '<span class=\"pro_info pro_info-indent pro_info_success\">' + count + ' result found!! </span><div class=clear></div>';
    else
    side_bar_html += '<span class=\"pro_info pro_info-indent pro_info_warning\"> No Result found!! </span><div class=clear></div>';

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var link= '/Place';
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var Mainicon = customMainIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: Mainicon.icon,
        shadow: Mainicon.shadow,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      });
        gmarkers[i] = marker;
      side_bar_html += '<div class=\"pro_curved-hz-2-1\" onclick="myclick('+i+');" onmouseover="mymouseover('+i+');" onmouseout="mymouseout('+i+');" ><div class=\"pro_text-shadow\"><a href=' + link + '>' + name + '</a><br>' + address + '</div></div>';
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, side_bar_html);


    }
    side_bar_html += "</div></div>";
  });
}

      function myclick(index) { 

        }

      function mymouseover(i) {
        gmarkers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }

      function mymouseout(i) {
        gmarkers[i].setAnimation(null);
        }

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, side_bar_html) {

document.getElementById("SideBar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', function() {
    //marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    //setTimeout(function(){ marker.setAnimation(null); }, 750);
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.close(map, marker);
    });

    var p=<?php echo $Zoom; ?>;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    p+=1;
    if(p>=20)
    {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    else
    {
    map.setZoom(p);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }
  });
}
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) that does what you are requesting (with function closure and a createMarker function).

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_noclosure.html) that doesn't use function closure.

Comment: but on mouse out info window closes itself...even if it is opened by clicking...where to change in the code?

Comment: 1. my example doesn't do that, where is your code that does?  2. this should be a new question.